# Javascript script doesn't work after adding it dynamically to component

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, dynamic

I created a component dynamically and I added the tag script to it but the code inside doesn't work
I tried a lot of solutions but none of them work for me, please check the code

[image: code pic]

[image: html pic]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can scripts be inserted with innerHTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197575/can-scripts-be-inserted-with-innerhtml)

Comment: No mate, if you checked the commented code you gonna see what I tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used jQuery document.ready and it's working now fine for me after injecting it with a dynamic component

```
 $(document).ready(function(){  
  $("#prep_abs_rup_eval").change(function(){ 
    if($("#prep_abs_rup_eval").val()=='A'){
        $("#prep_abs_rup_score").val("20");
    } else {
        $("#prep_abs_rup_score").val("10");
    }
 }); 
});
```